# Hipervínculo a un archivo, crystal reportes

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal report 8
Como se pasan parámetros a un hipervínculo a un archivo

El ejecutable lo inicia, pero si pongo parámetros no reconoce el archivo

No funciona esto
file:///C:\Documents and Settings\Mariano\Mis documentos\grabar.bat nombre apellido

Si funciona esto, pero al no tener parametros no me sirve.
file:///C:\Documents and Settings\Mariano\Mis documentos\grabar.bat
Como deben ponerse los parámetros

Gracias por anticipado